# Workaround for JavaFX Webview not supporting window.FileReader javascript

Tags: javascript, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

The following code indicates that the JavaFX Webview does not support the Javascript `window.FileReader` api:

`webEngine.loadContent("<html><body><script>alert(window.FileReader);</script></body></html>`

Are there any known workarounds?

Comment: I have the same problem and still getting that FileReader is undefined
how did you fix this issue?

Comment: JavaFX WebView doesn't support `FileReader` fully. There is an issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8207772

Comment: File API and FileReader will support in [8u212, openjfx12](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8207772) [scheduled dates](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/jdk8u)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does support FileReader. The problem is webengine/webview does not display alert boxes, confirmation boxes, or popup windows without some work on your part so that is actually what is failing. If you want alert boxes you need to create the dialog yourself:

```
    webEngine.setOnAlert
    (
        new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(WebEvent<String> arg0) 
            {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setHeaderText("Alert");
                alert.setContentText(arg0.getData());
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: I'm still getting Undefined when alerting FileReader, am I missing something?

Comment: I encountered similar issue for FileReader, any solution here?